# add hyperlink to kendo ui k-button?

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using kendo ui menu widgets from the web package of kendo ui. There is a problem in hyperlink the k-button is not working with an hyperlink inside.

```
<button class="k-button">
    <a href="http://localhost:5724/map.html">
        <font color = 'black'>See All Centers
    </a></font>
</button>
```

the button does not even responding an error: it is behaving as if there is no hyperlink attached with button.

Comment: Are you sure the path to the map.html is correct?

Comment: ya damn sure...the path is completely correct ...!1111

Comment: That wouldn't work because the button doesn't know what to do; you're wrapping an `a` tag inside a `button`.  See the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An anchor can directly be formatted as a button by simply adding `class="k-button"`

You should define it as:

```
<a href="http://localhost:5724/map.html" class="k-button"><font color = 'black'>See All Center</fonts></a>
```

BTW: The tags in your HTML example are not correctly balanced. Also consider using style attribute instead of fonts.